# Symfony2 Doctrine PHP Annotation for refClassRelationAlias

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a many-to-many self-referencing non-equal relationship for one of my tables. The database tables look something like:

```
Node
- id

Node_Relationship
- parent_id (FK of Node.id)
- child_id (FK of Node.id)
- PRIMARY KEY (parent_id, child_id)
```

This causes issues with Doctrine, giving a duplicate entry for that ID combination.

This thread, http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DC-329, mentions a fix at the very bottom of using refClassRelationAlias.

My question is, how do I implement this? I'm using the PHP annotation method to markup my classes, but they only mention using a YAML file, which I'm not currently doing.

Can I implement this without completely redoing everything into a YAML file? If so, how?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

My two fields are annotated like this:

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Module", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="module_relationships",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="child_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id",  
     *      referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    protected $parents;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Module", mappedBy="parents")
     */
    protected $children;
```

When I add something to the parent or child, I also set it's inverse. I use set and use the object's ID as the key, to avoid duplicates in the ArrayCollection.

Did they fix the bug and I'm just doing something wrong? Or is there still a bug with a different fix. I'm using Symfony version 2.0.12.

Thanks.

UPDATE 2:
Turns out I was creating duplicates unintentionally. Once I changed the function to actually prevent them, it seems to work just fine.

Comment: The fix is for doctrine 1.2 version.

Comment: Is there a fix for the latest version and I'm doing something wrong then?

Comment: I haven't worked with self referencing many-to-many relation yet. But still can you tell about scenario when duplicate entry problem occurs?

Comment: Doh, it turns out this was my own fault. As I mentioned, I was using the id as a key when I was setting to avoid duplicate values... however, the initially loaded ones were given no such key, so I was actually causing duplicates.

I switched from doing that to simply checking if it contained it before adding, and now it works just fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was my own fault. As I mentioned, I was using the id as a key when I was setting to avoid duplicate values... however, the initially loaded ones were given no such key, so I was actually causing duplicates. I switched from doing that to simply checking if it contained it before adding, and now it works just fine.